# Converting a WCF service to console application

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application

I have a WCF service. Now I would like to convert it to console application. Basically, it is a simple service. It only does 2 jobs depending on client request by PowerShell request.

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost:10000/backup/DoBackup?id=BackupClient1"
```

or

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost:10000/backup/DoBackup?id=BackupClient2"
```

My service listens on request for this 2 requests.

I have this WCF code:

```
    myService service = new myService(_settings);
    backupServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(service, _backupAddress);
    WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
    string address = "";
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = backupServiceHost .AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISnapshotServiceContract), binding, address);
    backupServiceHost .Open();
```

I can't use `WebServiceHost` and `WebHttpBinding` in my console app. What is the best replacement for this? I'm thinking to use simple `HttpClient`. But I'm not sure is it a correct selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't use command line parameters and avoid `WebServiceHost` altogether? You can then just compare your `args[]` from Main function (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) to determine if it is `BackupClient1` command or `BackupClient2` command.

If you want to take this concept further you can extract functionality of `BackupClient1` command and `BackupClient2` command into separate library and have frontends (WCF and command line) using same backend.

If you really need WCF service (as stated by comments below) please refer to this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-endpoint-in-code); you will have to provide your configuration and figure out how to indicate that you wish to end the process in nice way but it should boil down to something like this:

```
String baseAddress = "http://localhost:10000/backup";
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(myService)))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, baseAddress);
    host.Open();

    while(true) {
         // Figure out how to exit this loop - e.g. listen to some command from service
    }
}
```

Comment: But the client must request by ps Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost:10000/. So I can't use cmd argument

Comment: In that case you can refer to this sample how to instantiate WCF `ServiceHost` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-endpoint-in-code), however you will need to solve on how to stop the service - you will need to e.g. run forever loop after starting the service and additional command in the service to indicate that service should exit.